# Castle ActiveRecord DeleteAll on belongsto restraint

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord, castle

I have 2 classes with the following setup:

```
[ActiveRecord("ReceivedMessage")]
class ARReceivedMessage : ARBase<ARReceivedMessage>
```

and:

```
[ActiveRecord("ReceivedMessageReply")]
class ARReceivedMessageReply : ARBase<ARReceivedMessageReply>

[BelongsTo(Type = typeof(ARReceivedMessage), Column = "ReceivedMessageID")]
public ARReceivedMessage Message { get; set; }
```

When trying to clean up the database i first want to delete all the ReceivedMessageReply objects before deleting the ReceivedMessage itself. In code this brought me to the following:

Get all receivedMessages i want to delete:

```
ARReceivedMessage[] messagesToDelete = ARReceivedMessage.GetAll(messageCriterion);
```

Get the criterion for deleting all ReceivedMessageReplys and delete them:

```
ICriterion relatedCriterion = Restrictions.In("ReceivedMessageID", messagesToDelete);
ARReceivedMessageReply.DeleteAll(relatedCriterion);
```

Somehow activerecord tells me the following: 
could not resolve property: ReceivedMessageID of: ARReceivedMessageReply

Any idea where im making a mistake?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i had to use the following:

```
ICriterion relatedCriterion = Restrictions.In("Message", messagesToDelete);
```

So not the columnname/propertyname set by activerecord, but the property name itself. This was unexpected...